# TypeForwardedTo refuses to work for System.Windows.Input.ICommand in MonoTouch / VSMonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

I've implemented quite a few `TypeForwardedTo` routes using the suggestion in the accepted answer from [Is it possible to use a Portable Class Library that references System.Net in MonoDroid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361457/is-it-possible-to-use-a-portable-class-library-that-references-system-net-in-mon)

However, I'm now trying to add TypeForwardTo(System.Windows.Input.ICommand) to the list, and for some reason this type refuses to work.

Basically the error message I get is:

> Error 5   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  C:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\System.Windows.Touch\Forwarding.cs  9   42  System.Windows.Touch

I don't understand why this is as when I look at the VSMonoTouch copy of System.dll in Reflector then I can clearly see the ICommand type:

```
.namespace System.Windows.Input
{
    .class public interface abstract auto ansi ICommand
    {
        .event [mscorlib]System.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            .addon instance void System.Windows.Input.ICommand::add_CanExecuteChanged(class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler)
            .removeon instance void System.Windows.Input.ICommand::remove_CanExecuteChanged(class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler)
        }


        .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance bool CanExecute(object parameter) cil managed
        {
        }

        .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual instance void Execute(object parameter) cil managed
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Other types in System.dll are forwarding fine - i.e. only the last line is failing in:

```
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyObservableCollection<>))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler))]
[assembly: TypeForwardedTo(typeof(System.Windows.Input.ICommand))]
```

Also:
- I know that the MonoDroid redirect of this is working fine....
- I know that System.Windows.Input.ICommand was added comparatively recently to MonoTouch
- I have a suspicion that the fact that VSMonoTouch uses a .Net Framework Version of 1.0 might also be causing some issues (but I'm not sure I fully understand this).

Can anyone suggest what might be the cause of this? And what might be a cure?