# Type reference forwarding in the MonoDroid project requiring it

Tags: msbuild, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Regarding to the solution described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361457/is-it-possible-to-use-a-portable-class-library-that-references-system-net-in-mon), a third assembly is required to forward the type resolution to the correct assembly.
When adding this reference to the Android class library project using the type, the forwarding seems to not be done. The reference needs to be added in the Android application project which is the end point of the build process.

Does any solution exist to add the reference embedding the forwarding in the project requiring it ?

I mean, if in my solution architecture I use :

- MyApp.Core - PCL
- MyApp.Core.Droid - Android class library
- MyApp.UI.Droid - Android Application

The usage of System.Net namespace (System.Net.Socket.AddressFamily for example) is done in my ViewModel, which is located in MyApp.Core.Droid (redirection of MyApp.Core with some plugins). In this case, it is more logical (and readable) to have the reference in the MyApp.Core.Droid. But in the fact, the assembly resolution is done (from what I understand) when packaging the application, so in MyApp.UI.Droid. So in this case, the reference needs to be added to MyApp.UI.Droid in order to be found (failed if added to MyApp.Core.Droid).

In this case the solution works, but its quite obvious to understand for a new programmer joining the team which, has not been facing the trouble and understands why this reference needs to be added to the UI project...

I'm not sure my thought is easy to understand by the way I introduce it. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Thanks,

Guillaume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why this 'fails if added to MyApp.Core.Droid' - it feels like this should be added. However, I know that Xamarin have tweaked and changed the dependency resolution scripts a few times.

---

With that said, I think the best answer to your question is 'don't worry about it too much' - this is only a small inconveneinve right now and it will be resolved by Xamarin's updates 'soon'.

The current PCL support is something that I and a number of others have worked on in order to make things work. This set of 'hacks' is a workaround for the lack of 'proper PCL' support - it simulates what the Microsoft PCL build platform does on WindowsPhone, WPF, etc, but it isn't a perfect implementation.

Xamarin have now committed to 'proper PCL' support. When that happens then these type-forwarding dependencies will automatically be added. The good news is that this support is perhaps now only days, weeks or at most months away.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Stuart, I am just relieved to know that it is a "normal" behavior with the current PCL state, not a trouble on my side. Waiting for you speak at Evolve, hope you are ready :)