# How to structure a solution(s?) with both web and winform projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

What I'm hoping to learn is a best practice for how to combine, in Visual Studio, a web application and desktop application from the same work effort.

I have an assignment, for example, that includes an ASP.NET MVC front-end where a client inputs into a SQL Server database.  A winform reads that input from the database and takes actions on it.  The specific ins and outs aren't as important.

The ASP.NET MVC is obviously a Visual Studio project, with a VS unit test project supporting it.

The desktop application is a C# project referencing / bundled with two other winform projects.

Is it best to keep the web and winform projects together, or in separate solutions?  My team has taken a few hodgepodge approaches in this situation, going one way or the other, but I want to feel like I'm doing it "right."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what parts of the code are shared between the applications, but generally there is some in common.  In that case you would create a Library (DLL) project with the shared code and expose as "public" only the needed APIs.  You may even consider using  a [Portable Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238955/what-is-a-portable-class-library) that is referenced (as a project reference) by both the WebForm and WebApp projects.

In general I've found it convenient to keep the projects in one solution until if/when loading and building it becomes cumbersome due to the size, so I think you're close enough to "right" to feel it.