# One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I created a new .NET Core Class Library and added a Nuget package from an internal company Nuget server. I began getting the following error:

> Package XXXX is not compatible with netstandard1.5
>   (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5). Package XXXX 
>   1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.

I updated the project.json file to look like this but the same error persists.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "XXXXX": "1.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have insight on this?

Comment: @HansPassant To my understanding, the .NET Platform Standard is done now. There will be additive changes in the future, but not breaking ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Tl;dr** - it has to be `netstandard` [all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)!

To install a package in a .NET Core project, the package **and** all of its dependencies must be compatible with `netstandard1.X`.

It looks like your project targets `netstandard1.5`, but depends on a package that only targets `net45`. The only way to resolve this is to replace the dependency, or update it to a version that targets `netstandard`.

In some cases, `imports` will allow you to use a [Portable Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5238955/3191599) in a .NET Core application. This isn't a general cure-all for incompatible packages, but rather a temporary fix that works with packages that already target a smaller API.

Comment: I've seen a couple references that say including "portable-net4+win8" with net4 being the framework version will fix this issue. E.g. https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#using-imports-in-project-json.

Comment: @GrandMasterT Does importing `portable-net45+netcore45+wp8` work for you?

Comment: @GrandMasterT That can work only if the package is a Portable Class Library. It doesn't seem your package is that.

Comment: @NateBarbettini No, importing is not working in my case. I know that it does work with several other Nuget packages or libraries. EF and xUnit are just two examples.