# Referencing a legacy (.NET 4.0) assembly in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application.  I'm trying to add the ClosedXML NuGet package to my web project, but can't get past the following error.

Is it possible to reference a .NET 4.0 assembly in ASP.NET Core 1.0?

I've tried mucking w/ the dependencies and imports sections of project.json file, but haven't yet hit on anything that works.  Many thanks for your help.

```
Package ClosedXML 0.76.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package ClosedXML 0.76.0 supports:

- net35-client (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client)
- net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)

One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710474/one-or-more-packages-are-incompatible-with-netstandard-version-v1-5)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it was helpful!