# Portable DLL (.NetStandard 1.5) Nuget install issue

Tags: c#, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I have a problem about Portable dll  (.NetStandard 1.5) reference from Nuget.  I have 2 project once is A_PCL (.NetStandard 1.5) another is B_PCL (.NetStandard 1.5)

The following is project setting
[image]

[image]

When B_PCL direct reference A_PCL.dll is no problem
[image]

When I make A_PCL to Nuget package and install it in to B_PCL.  I got the following error

> Package A_PCL 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5). Package A_PCL 1.0.0 supports: portable50 (portable50,Version=v0.0)
>   One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.

How can I do?

Comment: Is A referencing other NuGet packages? If yes, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/37712137/97471

Comment: Your link is tow different type of project, but my both project's is same type of project, I don't know I got this error.  How can I resolve?

Comment: How is the link a different type of project? Both this and the link target netstandard1.5. Can you answer if A_PCL does have references to other external NuGet packages?

Comment: The link is talking about .Net Standard 1.5 and reference .Net Framework 4.5 package.  The error is "Package XXXX is not compatible with netstandard1.5 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5). Package XXXX 1.0 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5) One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.5.".  My both project's is .Net Standard 1.5

Comment: Please paste img of all references of project A. Also ensure you copied the very last version of A nuget package to your local repository and you are not using an old copy

Comment: Yes the issue on the link was a reference to a net45 package. Your issue may be you are referencing a portable50 package.